# how to import module kicost and pass arguments

Tags: python

I'm trying to import the module kicost in the python script and call the main function with arguments.
So far, I've been unsuccessful to do it after many trials.
The module has been installed with pip.

```
import sys, os

from kicost import *
import importlib

spam_spec = importlib.util.find_spec("kicost")
print(spam_spec)

# sys.argv.append('-h')

main()
exit()
```

Here is the execution log:

> ModuleSpec(name='kicost',
> loader=<_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at
> 0x101278160>,
> origin='/Users/sebo/Projects/python/pandas/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kicost/**init**.py',
> submodule_search_locations=['/Users/sebo/Projects/python/pandas/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kicost'])
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test-import-kicost.py",
> line 12, in 
> main() NameError: name 'main' is not defined

I guess there is something I don't understand with the import.
Could somebody help me? Thanks.

S/

Comment: There is no `main` function in kicost. You cannot do this. What is `kicost` anyway? Does it have documentation which explains how to use it? Or is it something you wrote?

Comment: kicost is a module associated with the open source kicad tool. https://github.com/xesscorp/KiCost. If I look into the source code of kicost, I see there is a main function defined in the __main__.py file.

Comment: `__main__.py` is so you can use `python -m kicost`. For your purposes, it would be simpler to use a shell script or alias to do what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I managed to do it:

```
import sys, os
import kicost.__main__ as kicost

sys.argv.append('-i=/Users/sebo/Projects/python/pandas/test.csv')
sys.argv.append('--currency=EUR')
sys.argv.append('--overwrite')

kicost.main()
exit()
```